# how to visible and hide view in listview item?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, adapter

I have A listview, and in list view I have A textview. So this text view is visible in every item of listview. So when I click on any Textview then it's visibility mus be gone. But when I'll click on another textview then current must gone and previous must be visible.
In adapter class I tried a lot of things but I did't find the correct way. So how can I get this thing in getView().

```
holder.floorNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.floorNo.getId() == v.getId()) {
                    final int position1 = listView
                            .getPositionForView((LinearLayout) v
                                    .getParent());

                } else {
                }
            }
        });
```

Here position1 is the current position of click. Pleas help me.

Comment: this work is done using javabeen getset methed whan u click the buttan tha notifatdatasetchange called

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag of textview as holder.settag(holder.floorNo). on click lister of floorNo get this tag by Textview floorno = (Textview) v.gettag();
Here you will get the clicked textview and add code for visible / invisible .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textview class member as a "reminder" to know which textview is hidden, something like this :

```
private View mHiddenView = null 
private int mFloorNoId = 0
....
....


    holder.floorNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mHiddenView !=null&&mFloorNoId!=0){
                // Show textview that was hidden
                mHiddenView.findViewById(mFloorNoId).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
            // Assign clicked view to hidden one and FloorNo id 
            mHiddenView = v;
            mFloorNoId = holder.floorNo.getId();
            // And hide it
            mHiddenView.findViewById(mFloorNoId).setVisibility(GONE);
        }       
    });
```

Comment: I need to hide only "holder.floorNo" and show the same also. So how I'll implement it?

Comment: Is floorNo a textview ? if yes you can maybe use it in place of v in `mHiddenTextview = (Textview) v;`

Comment: yes it is, but it is not working. I think i need to refresh the list view on everytime textview click, but how it is possible i don't know.

Comment: You can refresh listview with calling [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on/in your adapter

Comment: but I am not able to call the notifyDataSetChange() in onClick().

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Which adapter you are using .If you are using CursorAdapter then in CursorAdapter by overridien method newView() it is possible

```
  @Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ((TextView) (convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.main_body_item_title_second_pics)))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // do your stub here

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter<Strig>.

Answer (score 0):

maintain a list of boolean in your adapter indicating visibility of TextView holder.floorNo.

```
boolean[] visibilityArray;
```

in constructor

```
 visibilityArray; = new boolean[ no. Of Elements in your adapter ];
```

in getView() method

```
 holder.floorNo.setVisibility(visibilityArray[position]);   



         holder.floorNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                notifyStateChange(position);
            }
        });
```

notifyStateChange(position) method defined as follows

```
private void notifyStateChange(int position) {

        for(int i = 0; i<visibilityArray.length; i++){

visibilityArray[i] = true;
        }
visibilityArray[position] = false;
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```